# How do I increase my stamina?

Tags: fortnite-save-the-world

I run out of stamina easily and the only increase I've seen comes from upgrading a ninja character. What are my options for running faster and longer?

Comment: Not sure if this one's worth a full answer, but either equipping other heroes as your support with stamina bonuses, or getting the movement speed bonuses should help. There's not much else to do besides take breaks while running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game has changed drastically since the last answer was posted:

- Running no longer uses Stamina. Only abilities consume stamina, in addition to heavy attacks.
- Running faster can be done by either:

  - Recombobulating melee weapons with the *+#% movement speed" perk*
  - Using the melee *Six Feet Under* which has a unique perk of "Hitting an enemy with this weapon grants +6% movement speed for 5 seconds. Stacks up to 5 times."
  - Entering Shadow Stance upon a melee kill as any Ninja
  - Using the Ninja Dire.

    - In the Commander slot he grants +50% movement speed at night
    - In the Support slot he grants +25% movement speed at night
  - Spending 2 BluGlo on a Movement Speed pylon

Answer (score 2):

All heroes have some kind of bonus stat that is applied when they are in your hero squad. There are two kinds of bonus: a support bonus (left side hero), which gets applied no matter what, and a tactical bonus (right side), which only gets applied when the hero in the slot is star level 2 or higher.

There are some heroes that increase the amount of energy you have. I know Assassin Sarah has a 16% bonus to energy capacity as her support bonus. (This gives an extra 16 max energy.) Dim Mak increases the energy regeneration rate as a support bonus. There are probably some other heroes that also provide energy bonuses as well.